# Connecting laptop MS SQL Express server using PHP script on Hostinger

Tags: php, sql-server, web-hosting

[First time trying the code]I am trying to use a simple PHP file, that I uploaded to Hostinger, to connect and query my laptop's Microsoft SQL **Express** Server (to test the website, as the database is large to upload to the Hostinger database). The following **Ms SQL** connect gives an ***"HTTP ERROR 500" page*** error (*possibly because Hostinger does not support MsSQL):

```
<?php

$host = 'DESKTOP-SL59JDD\SQLEXPRESS';
$dbname = 'FXDatabase';
$username = 'sa';
$password = 'test123';

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($host, $username, $password)
or die(“Couldn’t connect to SQL Server on $host”);

?>
```

Also attempted **MySQL** connect as followed, which gives a ***"Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"*** error.

```
$host = 'DESKTOP-SL59JDD\SQLEXPRESS';
$dbname = 'FXDatabase';
$username = 'sa';
$password = 'test123';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    echo "Connection Successful!";
}
```

is there a permission on the Microsoft SQL Express server that I am missing to give to the *sa* user?

Comment: You can't connect from Hostinger to your laptop -- there is almost certainly a firewall or two between you, and even if not, you'd have to use a IP address or domain name, not a Windows host name.

Comment: I thought as much...thanks for confirming

Comment: The second attempt with the MySQL driver would never work, regardless of network connectivity, because Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL use incompatible network protocols.